# Unwind segue between two UIViewControllers that not belongs to the same UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, unwind-segue

I am currently developing an iOS application for both iPhone and iPad. I'm trying to use unwind segues to go back from an UIViewController to other, but there are not in the same UINavigationController. (From FilesPeriodViewController to FilesBatchViewController)[image: screenshot from my storyboard]

It's possible to do a unwind segue for two UIViewControllers that are not from the same UINavigationController?

I was trying using normal unwind segue, but it does not work, the error it throws is that UIViewController doesn't belong to the same UINavigationController

Comment: Did you try `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`?

Comment: That doesn´t work :( @Desdenova

Comment: How did you present it?

Comment: When I instantiate the UIViewVController that I want to goBack I put: `UIStoryboard *storyboard = [AkdemiaStoryboard storyboard];
  UINavigationController *navigationController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FilesEmployeeNavigation"];
  FilesBatchViewController *filesBatchViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Batch"];
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
` @Desdenova

Comment: Temporary, I just reload the UIViewController in the button's action. It works but isn't the most beautiful solution

Comment: Seems like you are over complicating things. From the looks of it that z shaped segue would take you to the period view controller with a simple perform segue and then you could call dismiss to go back.

Comment: I got it, I am going to try this. Thank you @Desdenova